# Java: Make opacity only apply to JPanel not components

Tags: java, swing

I got a JPanel called 'Main' which I managed to make transparent. The problem is, I only want to make the panel itself transparent, I want the components in it to be visible.

This bit of code is my Panel;

```
JPanel window=new JPanel();
static JTextArea dialog=new JTextArea(14,35);
JTextField input=new JTextField(35);
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(
    dialog,
    JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
    JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER
);

public Main() {
    super("Test");
    setSize(400,270);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    dialog.setEditable(false);
    dialog.setFocusable(false);
    dialog.setOpaque(false);
    scroll.setOpaque(false);
    scroll.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
    input.setOpaque(false);

    input.addKeyListener(this);     
    window.add(scroll);
    window.add(input);

    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    window.setBackground(new Color(255,200,0));

    add(window);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Now, when actually creating the window I use this;

```
Main Main = new Main();
Main.setOpacity(0.75f);
```

It does what it's supposed to which is make the panel and all it's components transparent.
However, I want only the panel to become transparent.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something?  Would not window.setOpaque(false) do the trick?

Comment: You'd think it would but it just removes the background color. If the background color is set that is

Comment: That’s how [`setOpacity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setOpacity(float)) is supposed to work: “*Sets the opacity of the window*”. What you want is *per-pixel translucency*. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setBackground(java.awt.Color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the background color of window to this as well.

```
new Color(255,200,0,0);
```

The last 0 sets the alpha - I believe 0 should make it transparent.